# How to Add Pushwoosh plugin for Android to Cordova IBM Worklight (@Eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins, pushwoosh

I want to implement the push notification to my cordova android application using [Pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/) library.

I am try to following [Pushwhoosh guide](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap). But from the begining , it requirs to add plugin from command.

**cordova plugin add pushwoosh-cordova-plugin**

But i am usin eclipse IDE , and dont know how to add those plugin,

Hope will some one will help to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.!

I have try the Below

@Command Prompt :

> cordova create PusTestApp
>
> cordova plugin add pushwoosh-cordova-plugin

**Fetching plugin "pushwoosh-cordova-plugin" via npm**

- Finall its add the plugin to there by created a folder with named"pushwoosh-cordova-plugin".
  -It contains PushNotifications.java and PushNotifications.js

@Eclipse :

- After I was open Ecliple create a WorkLight project and added android environment.
- Inside **"src"** folder added the **PushNotifications.java**
- Inside **"www/js"** folder added the **PushNotifications.js**
- Include that js file into index.html

Now if i run android project.

- It's shows error message as "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". at Pushnotification.js

Also i have tried to modify the "**cordova_plugin.js**" add a new module at module.exports=[{}], thats also not work. show some error.

Comment: I think you need to navigate to your project directory from command line and run the command.

Comment: Hi @HussamEddin I have tried that one, it's reply a error with "Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project." ..

Answer (score 0):

In Worklight Project, it is different to add cordova plugin. The way it should work is as the following:

1. You need to install the plugin on a sample Cordova project.
2. Use the
       Pluging Java code that is created from #1 in you WL project with the
       JS file and the whitelist configuration.
3. Add the Java code to your Android src folder under the package name.
4. Consume it through the JS file.

I did a sample project and I got the code:

PushNotifications.java

```
    //
// PushNotifications.java
//
// Pushwoosh, 01/07/12.
//
// Pushwoosh Push Notifications Plugin for Cordova Android
// www.pushwoosh.com
//
// MIT Licensed

package com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import com.pushwoosh.PushManager;
import com.pushwoosh.notification.SoundType;
import com.pushwoosh.notification.VibrateType;
import com.pushwoosh.PushManager.GetTagsListener;
import com.pushwoosh.BasePushMessageReceiver;
import com.pushwoosh.BaseRegistrationReceiver;
import com.pushwoosh.SendPushTagsCallBack;
import com.pushwoosh.internal.utils.GeneralUtils;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PushNotifications extends CordovaPlugin
{
    public static final String REGISTER = "registerDevice";
    public static final String UNREGISTER = "unregisterDevice";
    public static final String SET_TAGS = "setTags";
    public static final String START_GEO_PUSHES = "startGeoPushes";
    public static final String START_LOCATION_TRACKING = "startLocationTracking";
    public static final String STOP_GEO_PUSHES = "stopGeoPushes";
    public static final String STOP_LOCATION_TRACKING = "stopLocationTracking";
    public static final String START_BEACON_PUSHES = "startBeaconPushes";
    public static final String STOP_BEACON_PUSHES = "stopBeaconPushes";
    public static final String SET_BEACON_BACKGROUND_MODE = "setBeaconBackgroundMode";
    public static final String CREATE_LOCAL_NOTIFICATION = "createLocalNotification";
    public static final String CLEAR_LOCAL_NOTIFICATION = "clearLocalNotification";
    public static final String GET_TAGS = "getTags";
    public static final String ON_DEVICE_READY = "onDeviceReady";
    public static final String GET_PUSH_TOKEN = "getPushToken";
    public static final String GET_HWID = "getPushwooshHWID";
    public static final String GET_LAUNCH_NOTIFICATION = "getLaunchNotification";

    boolean receiversRegistered = false;
    boolean broadcastPush = true;
    JSONObject startPushData = null;

    HashMap<String, CallbackContext> callbackIds = new HashMap<String, CallbackContext>();
    PushManager mPushManager = null;

    private String TAG = "PWCordovaPlugin";

    /**
     * Called when the activity receives a new intent.
     */
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        startPushData = getPushFromIntent(intent);
        checkMessage(intent);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BaseRegistrationReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRegisterActionReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            checkMessage(intent);
        }
    };

    //Registration of the receivers
    public void registerReceivers()
    {
        if (receiversRegistered)
            return;

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + ".action.PUSH_MESSAGE_RECEIVE");

        //comment this code out if you would like to receive the notifications in the notifications center when the app is in foreground
        if (broadcastPush)
            cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);

        //registration receiver
        cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + "." + PushManager.REGISTER_BROAD_CAST_ACTION));

        receiversRegistered = true;
    }

    public void unregisterReceivers()
    {
        if (!receiversRegistered)
            return;

        try
        {
            cordova.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // pass. for some reason Phonegap call this method before onResume. Not Android lifecycle style...
        }

        try
        {
            cordova.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //pass through
        }

        receiversRegistered = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(boolean multitasking)
    {
        super.onResume(multitasking);
        registerReceivers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(boolean multitasking)
    {
        super.onPause(multitasking);
        unregisterReceivers();
    }

    /**
     * The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.
     */
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void initialize(JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        JSONObject params = null;
        try
        {
            params = data.getJSONObject(0);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "No parameters has been passed to onDeviceReady function. Did you follow the guide correctly?");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            String packageName = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            ApplicationInfo ai = cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

            if (ai.metaData != null && ai.metaData.containsKey("PW_NO_BROADCAST_PUSH"))
                broadcastPush = !(ai.metaData.getBoolean("PW_NO_BROADCAST_PUSH"));

            Log.d(TAG, "broadcastPush = " + broadcastPush);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            //make sure the receivers are on
            registerReceivers();

            startPushData = getPushFromIntent(cordova.getActivity().getIntent());

            String appid = null;
            if (params.has("appid"))
                appid = params.getString("appid");
            else
                appid = params.getString("pw_appid");

            PushManager.initializePushManager(cordova.getActivity(), appid, params.getString("projectid"));
            mPushManager = PushManager.getInstance(cordova.getActivity());
            mPushManager.onStartup(cordova.getActivity());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Pushwoosh", "Missing pw_appid parameter. Did you follow the guide correctly?");
            return;
        }
    }

    private boolean internalRegister(JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        try
        {
            callbackIds.put("registerDevice", callbackContext);
            mPushManager.registerForPushNotifications();
        }
        catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e)
        {
            callbackIds.remove("registerDevice");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Pushwoosh", "registering for push notifications failed");

            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return true;
        }

        checkMessage(cordova.getActivity().getIntent());
        return true;
    }

    private JSONObject getPushFromIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (null == intent)
            return null;

        if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT))
        {
            String pushString = intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT);
            JSONObject pushObject = null;
            try
            {
                pushObject = new JSONObject(pushString);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return pushObject;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void checkMessage(Intent intent)
    {
        if (null != intent)
        {
            if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT))
            {
                doOnMessageReceive(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT))
            {
                doOnRegistered(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT))
            {
                doOnUnregistered(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
            {
                doOnRegisteredError(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT));
            }
            else if (intent.hasExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT))
            {
                doOnUnregisteredError(intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT));
            }

            intent.removeExtra(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT);
            intent.removeExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_EVENT);
            intent.removeExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_EVENT);
            intent.removeExtra(PushManager.REGISTER_ERROR_EVENT);
            intent.removeExtra(PushManager.UNREGISTER_ERROR_EVENT);

            cordova.getActivity().setIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private boolean internalUnregister(JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        callbackIds.put("unregisterDevice", callbackContext);

        try
        {
            mPushManager.unregisterForPushNotifications();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            callbackIds.remove("unregisterDevice");
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean internalSendTags(JSONArray data, final CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        JSONObject params;
        try
        {
            params = data.getJSONObject(0);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("Pushwoosh", "No tags information passed (missing parameters)");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<String> nameItr = params.keys();
        Map<String, Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        while (nameItr.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {
                String name = nameItr.next();
                paramsMap.put(name, params.get(name));
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("Pushwoosh", "Tag parameter is invalid");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        callbackIds.put("setTags", callbackContext);

        final class SendTagsListenerImpl implements SendPushTagsCallBack
        {
            @Override
            public void onSentTagsSuccess(Map<String, String> skippedTags)
            {
                CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("setTags");
                if (callback == null)
                    return;

                callback.success(new JSONObject(skippedTags));
                callbackIds.remove("setTags");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSentTagsError(Exception e)
            {
                CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("setTags");
                if (callback == null)
                    return;

                callback.error(e.getMessage());
                callbackIds.remove("setTags");
            }

            @Override
            public void taskStarted()
            {
            }
        }

        PushManager.sendTags(cordova.getActivity(), paramsMap, new SendTagsListenerImpl());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackId)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Plugin Method Called: " + action);

        if (GET_PUSH_TOKEN.equals(action))
        {
            callbackId.success(PushManager.getPushToken(cordova.getActivity()));
            return true;
        }

        if (GET_HWID.equals(action))
        {
            callbackId.success(PushManager.getPushwooshHWID(cordova.getActivity()));
            return true;
        }

        if (ON_DEVICE_READY.equals(action))
        {
            initialize(data, callbackId);
            checkMessage(cordova.getActivity().getIntent());
            return true;
        }

        if (REGISTER.equals(action))
        {
            return internalRegister(data, callbackId);
        }

        if (UNREGISTER.equals(action))
        {
            return internalUnregister(data, callbackId);
        }

        if (SET_TAGS.equals(action))
        {
            return internalSendTags(data, callbackId);
        }

        if (START_GEO_PUSHES.equals(action) || START_LOCATION_TRACKING.equals(action))
        {
            if (mPushManager == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            mPushManager.startTrackingGeoPushes();
            return true;
        }

        if (STOP_GEO_PUSHES.equals(action) || STOP_LOCATION_TRACKING.equals(action))
        {
            if (mPushManager == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            mPushManager.stopTrackingGeoPushes();
            return true;
        }
        if (START_BEACON_PUSHES.equals(action))
        {
            if (mPushManager == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            mPushManager.startTrackingBeaconPushes();
            return true;
        }

        if (STOP_BEACON_PUSHES.equals(action))
        {
            if (mPushManager == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            mPushManager.stopTrackingBeaconPushes();
            return true;
        }

        if (SET_BEACON_BACKGROUND_MODE.equals(action))
        {
            try
            {
                boolean type = data.getBoolean(0);
                PushManager.setBeaconBackgroundMode(cordova.getActivity(), type);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if (CREATE_LOCAL_NOTIFICATION.equals(action))
        {
            JSONObject params = null;
            try
            {
                params = data.getJSONObject(0);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                //config params: {msg:"message", seconds:30, userData:"optional"}
                String message = params.getString("msg");
                Integer seconds = params.getInt("seconds");
                if (message == null || seconds == null)
                    return false;

                String userData = params.getString("userData");

                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                if (userData != null)
                    extras.putString("u", userData);

                PushManager.scheduleLocalNotification(cordova.getActivity(), message, extras, seconds);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Not correct parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if (CLEAR_LOCAL_NOTIFICATION.equals(action))
        {
            PushManager.clearLocalNotifications(cordova.getActivity());
            return true;
        }

        if (GET_LAUNCH_NOTIFICATION.equals(action))
        {
            // unfortunately null object can only be returned as String
            if (startPushData != null)
            {
                callbackId.success(startPushData);
            }
            else
            {
                callbackId.success((String) null);
            }
            return true;
        }

        if ("setMultiNotificationMode".equals(action))
        {
            PushManager.setMultiNotificationMode(cordova.getActivity());
            return true;
        }

        if ("setSingleNotificationMode".equals(action))
        {
            PushManager.setSimpleNotificationMode(cordova.getActivity());
            return true;
        }

        if ("setSoundType".equals(action))
        {
            try
            {
                Integer type = (Integer) data.get(0);
                if (type == null)
                    return false;

                PushManager.setSoundNotificationType(cordova.getActivity(), SoundType.fromInt(type));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "No sound parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if ("setVibrateType".equals(action))
        {
            try
            {
                Integer type = (Integer) data.get(0);
                if (type == null)
                    return false;

                PushManager.setVibrateNotificationType(cordova.getActivity(), VibrateType.fromInt(type));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "No vibration parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if ("setLightScreenOnNotification".equals(action))
        {
            try
            {
                boolean type = (boolean) data.getBoolean(0);
                PushManager.setLightScreenOnNotification(cordova.getActivity(), type);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if ("setEnableLED".equals(action))
        {
            try
            {
                boolean type = (boolean) data.getBoolean(0);
                PushManager.setEnableLED(cordova.getActivity(), type);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if ("setColorLED".equals(action))
        {
            try
            {
                String colorString = (String) data.get(0);
                if (colorString == null)
                    return false;

                int colorLed = GeneralUtils.parseColor(colorString);
                PushManager.setColorLED(cordova.getActivity(), colorLed);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        if (GET_TAGS.equals(action))
        {
            callbackIds.put("getTags", callbackId);

            final class GetTagsListenerImpl implements GetTagsListener
            {
                @Override
                public void onTagsReceived(Map<String, Object> tags)
                {
                    CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("getTags");
                    if (callback == null)
                        return;

                    callback.success(new JSONObject(tags));
                    callbackIds.remove("getTags");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e)
                {
                    CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("getTags");
                    if (callback == null)
                        return;

                    callback.error(e.getMessage());
                    callbackIds.remove("getTags");
                }
            }

            PushManager.getTagsAsync(cordova.getActivity(), new GetTagsListenerImpl());
            return true;
        }

        if (action.equals("getPushHistory"))
        {
            ArrayList<String> pushHistory = mPushManager.getPushHistory();
            callbackId.success(new JSONArray(pushHistory));
            return true;
        }

        if (action.equals("clearPushHistory"))
        {
            mPushManager.clearPushHistory();
            return true;
        }

        if (action.equals("clearNotificationCenter"))
        {
            PushManager.clearNotificationCenter(cordova.getActivity());
            return true;
        }

        if (action.equals("setApplicationIconBadgeNumber"))
        {
            try
            {
                Integer badgeNumber = data.getJSONObject(0).getInt("badge");
                if (badgeNumber == null)
                    return false;

                mPushManager.setBadgeNumber(badgeNumber);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        if (action.equals("getApplicationIconBadgeNumber"))
        {
            Integer badgeNumber = new Integer(mPushManager.getBadgeNumber());
            callbackId.success(badgeNumber);
            return true;
        }

        if (action.equals("addToApplicationIconBadgeNumber"))
        {
            try
            {
                Integer badgeNumber = data.getJSONObject(0).getInt("badge");
                if (badgeNumber == null)
                    return false;
                mPushManager.addBadgeNumber(badgeNumber);
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "No parameters passed (missing parameters)");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Invalid action : " + action + " passed");
        return false;
    }

    private void doOnRegistered(String registrationId)
    {
        CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("registerDevice");
        if (callback == null)
            return;

        callback.success(registrationId);
        callbackIds.remove("registerDevice");
    }

    private void doOnRegisteredError(String errorId)
    {
        CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("registerDevice");
        if (callback == null)
            return;

        callback.error(errorId);
        callbackIds.remove("registerDevice");
    }

    private void doOnUnregistered(String registrationId)
    {
        CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("unregisterDevice");
        if (callback == null)
            return;

        callback.success(registrationId);
        callbackIds.remove("unregisterDevice");
    }

    private void doOnUnregisteredError(String errorId)
    {
        CallbackContext callback = callbackIds.get("unregisterDevice");
        if (callback == null)
            return;

        callback.error(errorId);
        callbackIds.remove("unregisterDevice");
    }

    private void doOnMessageReceive(String message)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "message is: " + message);
        final String jsStatement = String.format("cordova.require(\"pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification\").notificationCallback(%s);", message);
        //webView.sendJavascript(jsStatement);

        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsStatement);
            }
        });
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BasePushMessageReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onMessageReceive(Intent intent)
        {
            doOnMessageReceive(intent.getStringExtra(JSON_DATA_KEY));
        }
    };
}
```

PushNotification.js

```
function initPushwoosh()
{
    var pushNotification = cordova.require("pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification");

    //set push notifications handler
    document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
        var title = event.notification.title;
        var userData = event.notification.userdata;

        if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
            console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
        }

        alert(title);
    });

    //initialize Pushwoosh with projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER", pw_appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID". This will trigger all pending push notifications on start.
    pushNotification.onDeviceReady({ projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER", pw_appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID" });

    //register for pushes
    pushNotification.registerDevice(
        function(status) {
            var pushToken = status;
            console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
        },
        function(status) {
            console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
        }
    );
}
```

config.xml:

```
<access origin="*.pushwoosh.com" />
```

Comment: Hi @Hussam Eddin, Thanks for your reply., I was already tried that one., and also try some other way also., am very new to the Worklight and cordova., can you suggest me if any tutorial links if availble.

Comment: Hello Hussam, After i update Mobilefirst studio, i can access third party plugin. but get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID". Please suggest me to resolve this issue.